# Cannot connect to SAP HANA 2.0 using JDBC

Tags: hana

I'm trying to connect to SAP HANA 2.0 using JDBC. I took the driver `ngdbc.jar` from the Eclipse plugin that I installed in Windows.

Problem is that I always get the same error `[Connection refused: connect], -813` even when I set a random IP address in the connection string.

The Eclipse plugin connects perfectly:

[image]

What could be the problem? This is the `ngdbc.jar` trace:

```
ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
Process-ID: 3140
package package com.sap.db.jdbc, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.6, SAP HANA JDBC Driver, SAP SE, 2.0.14-2d2417a0b831eafc24c4a6d30206b73d62a858e5 on Java 1.8.0_131


---- Thread 3e3abc88 main Timestamp: 2017-07-11 22:47:06.243
new Connection 'jdbc:sap://192.168.1.85:39015/'
user=SYSTEM
password=***
HOSTLIST: [192.168.1.85:39015,]
new RTEException: SQLSTART_REQUIRED(5) -813 Cannot connect to host 192.168.1.85:39015 [Connection refused: connect], -813.
whereAmIjava.lang.Throwable
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.trace.Tracer.whereAmI(Tracer.java:333)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.RTEException.<init>(RTEException.java:46)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.RTEException.<init>(RTEException.java:23)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.Session._openSocket(Session.java:1005)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.Session.openSocket(Session.java:416)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.Session$1.open(Session.java:915)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.Topology.getSession(Topology.java:214)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver._connect(Driver.java:814)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:159)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at fdic.LoadBankReferenceData$.delayedEndpoint$fdic$LoadBankReferenceData$1(LoadBankReferenceData.scala:20)
    at fdic.LoadBankReferenceData$delayedInit$body.apply(LoadBankReferenceData.scala:12)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at fdic.LoadBankReferenceData$.main(LoadBankReferenceData.scala:12)
    at fdic.LoadBankReferenceData.main(LoadBankReferenceData.scala)

using null
=> FAILED
```

And this is the code (in Scala):

```
  Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");  
  val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sap://192.168.1.85:39015/", 
      "SYSTEM", "xxxxx");
```

**UPDATE**

The code below throws the exact same error (this time in Java to rule out Scala problems):

```
Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sap://192.168.1.85:39015/?databaseName=VBK_BANK_0001", 
          "VBK_BANK_0001", "xxxxxxx");
```

I get the same error: `[Cannot connect to host 192.168.1.85:39015 [Connection refused: connect], -813.]`

In Elipse:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to try to connect to the SystemDB of a multi-database-container (MDC) setup of HANA. As the SystemDB is special and don't run in an indexserver process, you would use a different port (...13) to connect to it.
However, usually one would want to connect to a tenant database instead. For this, the jdbc URL needs to contain then name of the database as a parameter. The HANA documentation contains the details on this.

Comment: Lars, if I use port 39013 instead of 39015 everything works perfectly, including user SYSTEM and other users, why is that?

Comment: That's the external port for the nameserver process that runs the SystemDB. I highly recommend to have a read of the documentation.